# Dynamic regex matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some strings like the following ones :

```
var resource1 = '/myapi/person/pascal/address/town';
var resource2 = '/myapi/person/john/address/town';
var resource3 = '/myapi/person/messi/address/town';
```

This is what I tried so far :

The pattern is :

```
var pattern = '/myapi/person/(.*)/address/town';
```

This is what I tried so far :

```
var resource1 = '/myapi/person/pascal/address/town';
var resource2 = '/myapi/person/john/address/town';
var resource3 = '/myapi/person/messi/address/town';
var pattern = '/myapi/person/(.*)/address/town';

var pattern = new RegExp(pattern);
if (pattern.test(resource1)){
    console.log('yes');   
}
```

**Question**

How can I dynamically use that pattern to check if `resource1`, `resource2` or `resource3` match that `pattern`?

Regards.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I would recommend you to read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Store the strings in an array instead of variables.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should work:

```
/\/myapi\/person\/(.*)\/address\/town/
```

It can be used like so:

```
var string = '/myapi/person/pascal/address/town';
var re = /\/myapi\/person\/(.*)\/address\/town/;
re.test(string); //will return true
```

I encourage you to take a look it how it works here:
https://regexr.com/3ri4m

Comment: It is not useful to add the g|global flag to the .test method: "If the regex has the global flag set, test() will advance the lastIndex of the regex. A subsequent use of test() will start the search at the substring of str specified by lastIndex" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using stricter pattern. Use a negated character class instead of a greedy wildcard.

```js
let resources = ['/myapi/person/pascal/address/town',
                 '/myapi/person/john/address/town',
                 '/myapi/person/messi/address/town'];

var regex = new RegExp('/myapi/person/([^/]+)/address/town');
for (var i = 0, len = resources.length; i < len; i++) {
  if(regex.test(resources[i]))
    console.log(`valid: ${resources[i]}`);   
}
```

You have put a capture group around the person names variable. If you intend to capture those you can use .exec instead of .test:

```js
let resources = ['/myapi/person/pascal/address/town',
                 '/myapi/person/john/address/town',
                 '/myapi/person/messi/address/town'];

var regex = new RegExp('/myapi/person/([^/]+)/address/town');
for (var i = 0, len = resources.length; i < len; i++) {
  if ((m = regex.exec(resources[i])) !== null) {
          console.log(m[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Pato was any of the answers helpful to you?